# Where does the initial sys.path come from

Tags: python, import, path

I'm trying to figure out where does the initial `sys.path` value come from. One ubuntu system suddenly (by which I mean probably manually by someone doing something weird) lost entries at the end of the array.

All other hosts: `['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']`

That host: `['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`

The `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7` path is the one I actually care about. But where does it come from on the healthy nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from the `python-support` package, specifically from the `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python-support.pth` file that is installed.

There shouldn't be any modules installed to that directory manually and any package installing modules to that directory should have a dependency on the python-support package, so you shouldn't have to worry about whether it is in `sys.path` or not.

Comment: Nice. Apparently some files from python-support were removed (.pth), so even though python-support was there, it didn't update the directories. apt-get install --reinstall on python-support and all python-* packages helped.